# Schildt's C# book 4.0 and and topicality in actual version c#

Tags: c#

`
using System;

```
class Example2
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int x; 
        int у; 
        х = 100; 
        Console.WriteLine("х содержит " + х);
        у = х / 2;
        Console.Write("у содержит х / 2: ");
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
}
```

`Can I use this book for learning C# because I wrote code from book in IDE Visual Studio and it is does not work. [screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhB3g.png)
Please help me corect this code or recommend book. [screenshot from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggsso.png). Thanks

Comment: yes you can use the book, the book's reputation or value is not under question because of some syntax, compile errors

Comment: You need to share your code in the question itself. Image of code is not readable and we can not use the code from image to reproduce the issue you are facing.

Comment: @BrianOgden That shouldn‘t matter. I believe this should compile. Are you using the same character for x everywhere? Looks like the compiler thinks x and x are not the same.

Comment: @NoelWidmer you are right, it should compile fine, I deleted my comments about code adjustments

Comment: I can [confirm](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AEA54H). @NoelWidmer

Comment: edited @ChristianGollhardt

Comment: Yeah u right compiler thinks that x and x nit same, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your character with the error is [`х`](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%D1%85&mode=char).

> CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER HA

You define the variable with the [`x`](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=x&mode=char)

> LATIN SMALL LETTER X

So indeed, they are 2 different characters. Decide for one.